# Updating workflow - new functionality not being used

Tags: flowgear

I'm busy playing around with various things, and am making changes a fair bit for educational purposes.

However, now, any changes I make are not being accepted and old behaviour is still happening. IN this case, I had a email watcher setup to write a file to our domain controller and send an SMS.
I changed it to do something different, but no number of stop and restarts help - it continues to do the first action.

Pointers welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the *Stop All* in the run now screen. This will stop all the workflow instances.
However, if the workflow is set to *always on*, it will pull up again automatically after a few minutes.

It is best if you disable *always on*, and set it back to *always on*.

Hope this helps

Comment: I did try that, but it did not work. Since then, I was in touch with support and seems to have been a quirk - since fixed.